# html ajax / jquery get JSON data from remote server using JSONP/JSON

Tags: jquery, json, html, jsonp

i use jqChart plugin to display charts on mobile devices, so now the HTML file resides on the mobile device.

The Server takes in two parameters like this

```
  http://somedomain:15025/Service1.svc/storewise_sales_qty_asp/{param1},{param2}
```

and displays a JSON response.

here is a part of HTML Code

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#jqChart').jqChart({
                title: { text: 'Binding to Remote Data' },
                animation: { duration: 1 },
                shadows: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                dataSource: {
                    ajax: {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://somedomain:15025/Service1.svc/storewise_sales_qty_asp/26670,26770",
                contentType:"application/json",
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain:true,
                        data: "",
                    }
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        type: 'column',
                        xValuesField: {
                            name: 'Store',
                            type: 'string' // string, numeric, dateTime
                        },
                        yValuesField: 'Qty'
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

when i try to access the HTML file. it goes blank. the data is not received or something. i am new to j query and java. what do i do.

Comment: Firstly, check your console. Any error? Secondly, you cannot make POST request to get jsonp. Thirdly, to make a cross domain request, server has to allow it

Comment: Just for clarity I guess A Wolf means the console in Firebug. If you're not using it, it will probably help for issues like this

Comment: Is your serverside (somedomain:15025) also configured for crossdomain? If not, you still not allowed to use the data because you dont't have access to it... To fix this, make sure that the domain your HTML is running in is configured in the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"-header in your serverresponse

Comment: @A Wolf : i just checked the console, the page was going blank because there was no j query reference. i fixed it. now the page is loading :) the issue remains, data is not fetched. @Pazcal de Jonge: And yes, the server side is configured for crossdomain.